# Is there a way to change the default port (9443) of the token endpoint available for the JWT Grant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The WSO2 offers, in the [JWT Grant](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/JWT+Grant), an endpoint with the format `https://WSO2_URL:9443/oauth2/token`.

Is there a way to change that port to 8243?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already there in APIM, and it's recommended to use that instead of above one.

`https://WSO2_APIM_HOSTNAME:8243/token`

Comment: Hi Bee, could you add a reference to the doc where it says that's the recommended one please? In https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/JWT+Grant it only refers to 9443/oauth2/token...

Comment: `:9443/oauth2/token` is exposed by internal identity components and APIM fronts it by `:8243/token`. In all other grant types, `:8243/token` is mentioned. There is no reason for JWT grant to use the internal URL. Docs ideally should be modified to keep consistency.

Comment: For refresh grant type, it's a must to use the `/token` API. For other grant types it's fine to use either one. Recommondation is only there to maintain consistancy.

Comment: I appreciate you explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change it.
Set the offset in the Ports section of `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml. E.g., <Offset>3</Offset>`.`<PRODUCT_HOME>` can be like `/opt/wso2-am-2.1.0` (your installation directory).